# Import error:Pyqt

Tags: pyqt, python-sip

While installing pyqt in windows 7 gives error:

D:\pyqt>python configure.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 32, in 
    import sipconfig
ImportError: No module named sipconfig

How to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to build PyQt from source. Before you can do that, you must build and install SIP (clearly stated on the [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and [PyQt5](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) download page)

You can obtain the SIP source code from riverbank computing (see [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download)). You will then need to build SIP before you can build PyQt.

**Note, since you are on windows, you probably dno't need to do any of this building, and can just install from the precompiled installers which are available on the download pages I linked to above.**